# Wordpress wp_query get result into variables

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently I'm using `get_posts` to get the 10 latest posts, but the problem is that I don't get all information. For example I can't access the post category or author.

I would like to use `WP_Query` with `get_the_title()`, `get_the_post_thumbnail`, `get_permalink()` etc. The results have to be stored into variables.

My setup:

```
$latest_posts = get_posts( array(
        'category_name'  => 'Allgemein',
            'posts_per_page' => 10,
                "orderby"        => "date",
                    "order"          => "DESC"
    ) );




    // Post 1 -- Category: Allgemein
    if ( isset( $latest_posts[0] ) ) {  // array zero-based index.
        // $post1_category = $latest_posts[0]->post_category;
        $post1_date = $latest_posts[0]->post_date;
        $post1_title = $latest_posts[0]->post_title;
        // $post1_tags = $latest_posts[0]->post_tags;
        $post1_author = $latest_posts[0]->post_author;
        $post1_content = $latest_posts[0]->post_content;
        $post1_thumbnail = $latest_posts[0]->get_the_post_thumbnail;
    }

    // Post 2 -- Category: Allgemein
    if ( isset( $latest_posts[1] ) ) {
        // $post2_category = $latest_posts[1]->post_category;
        $post2_date = $latest_posts[1]->post_date;
        $post2_title = $latest_posts[1]->post_title;
        // $post2_tags = $latest_posts[1]->post_tags;
        $post2_author = $latest_posts[1]->post_author;
        $post2_content = $latest_posts[1]->post_content;
        $post2_thumbnail = $latest_posts[1]->get_the_post_thumbnail;
    }

    Post3-10
    ....
```

And in my `index.php`:

```
<div class="title">
   <?php echo $post1_title?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the categories, use the function [`wp_get_post_categories`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_categories/):

```
$post1_category = wp_get_post_categories($latest_posts[0]->ID);
```

To get the tags, use the function [`wp_get_post_tags`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_tags):

```
$post1_tags = wp_get_post_tags($latest_posts[0]->ID);
```

WordPress has more functions to retrieve the post data using the post ID. Follow:

1. [Get the Title](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/)
2. [Get the post thumbnail URL](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/)

Your variable `$latest_posts[X]` is a `WP_Post Object`, wich contains some data. See the full data list in the [WP_Post Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post).